# Cumulative distribution function - checking whether my answer is correct

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A random variable X has a cumulative distribution function

$$F(x) = {Ax+B}$$
if

0 < x < 3 (x is greater than or equal to xero)

0 if x < 0 (x is smaller or equal to zero)

1 if x > 3 (x is greater than or equal to 3)

The question is find the constants A and B and find the pdf(x)

What I have done: evaluated Ax + B at x=0 which gives just a B

evaluated Ax + B at x=3 which gives 3A + B

Taking these two together, equated B to zero and 3A + B to 1 which gives A = 1/3

Is this the correct way?

Comment: Yes, your calculations are correct assuming that the request for the pdf of $X$ is taken to mean that $X$ is a _continuous_ random variable. For _mixed_ random variables, the method will not work. If you have never heard of mixed random variables, ignore everything in this comment after the word "correct".

Comment: Thank you so much!